# How do I know if one class is superclass of another, given that I only have the fully qualified names of the classes as strings?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I need to know if the class represented by one string is superclass (directly or transitively) of another class also represented as a string. For instance:

```
String class1 = "java.lang.Object";
String class2 = "java.lang.Exception";

assertTrue( isSuperclass( class1, class2 ) );
```

I tried to get the IType for the second class and check its superclassName. This is how I tried:

```
/**
 * Checks if class1 is directly or transitively superclass of class2.
 */
private boolean isSuperclass(final String class1, final String class2)
{
    try
    {
        String className = class2;
        while (className!=null)
        {
            final IType type = this.javaProject.findType(className);
            if (type == null)
            {
                break;
            }

            className = type.getSuperclassName();
            if (class1.equals(className))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
    catch (final JavaModelException e)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

The problem is that getSuperclassName returns only the class name, not its fully qualified name. For this reason, I can't call javaProject.findType again in the loop to check if any transitive superclass of class2 is equals to class1.

So if I call:

```
isSuperclass( "java.lang.Throwable", "my.exceptions.Exception" )
```

It will return false, because

```
 javaProject.findType("my.exceptions.Exception").getSuperclassName()
```

returns only "ParentException", then the next call will be

```
 javaProject.findType("ParentException")
```

which returns a null IType, since its not the class fully qualified name. This only occurs with the classes declared in the own application being analyzed; for API classes getSuperclassName returns the fully qualified name.

I also thought of checking isSuperclass via ITypeBindings, but I don't know how to get an ITypeBinding from the fully qualified name String, or from the IType.

Any ideas on how I can check if a class is superclass of another?

**EDIT: Solutions based on Class.forName won't work on my context.**

Comment: the instanceof keyword can help you there.

Comment: @Stultuske: Not given the starting point of class name strings.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get how instanceof can help on that. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @EijiAdachi: Can you actually load the classes in question? (I don't know anything about Eclipse plugins.)

Comment: Yes, the corresponding Types are loaded.

Comment: if you can load the classes based on those Strings, you should be able to create instances as well, not?

Comment: @Stultuske: Yes, you could create an instance of one of them. But A) That's probably not a good idea, particularly if it only has constructors that require arguments, and B) You wouldn't have anything to use as the right-hand operand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer from  T.J. Crowder, the comment from  Brian and the code in [this page](https://sdqweb.ipd.kit.edu/wiki/JDT_Tutorial:_Class_Loading_in_a_running_plugin), I built this answer:

```
public boolean isSuperclass(final String className1, final String className2)
{
    //build a URL Class Loader
    final String[] classPathEntries = JavaRuntime.computeDefaultRuntimeClassPath(iJavaProject);
    final List<URL> urlList = new ArrayList<URL>();
    for (int i = 0; i < classPathEntries.length; i++)
    {
        final String entry = classPathEntries[i];
        final IPath path = new Path(entry);
        final URL url = path.toFile().toURI().toURL();
        urlList.add(url);
    }
    final ClassLoader parentClassLoader = iJavaProject.getClass().getClassLoader();
    final URL[] urls = urlList.toArray(new URL[urlList.size()]);
    final URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls, parentClassLoader);

    // check if is superclass
    final Class<?> class1 = Class.forName(className1, true, classLoader);
    final Class<?> class2 = Class.forName(className2, true, classLoader);
    return class1.isAssignableFrom(class2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**If** you can actually load the classes in question, you can use [`Class#isAssignableFrom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-):

```
Class c1 = Class.forName(class1);
Class c2 = Class.forName(class2);
if (c1.isAssignableFrom(c2)) {
    // c1 is a superclass or superinterface of c2
}
```

From the docs:

> `public boolean isAssignableFrom(Class<?> cls)`
>
> Determines if the class or interface represented by this `Class` object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified `Class` parameter. It returns `true` if so; otherwise it returns `false`.

So for instance:

```
String class1 = "java.lang.Object";
String class2 = "java.util.HashMap";
Class c1 = Class.forName(class1);
Class c2 = Class.forName(class2);
System.out.println(c1.isAssignableFrom(c2)); // true
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/jWanHU)

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work in the context of an eclipse plugin (not sure why, but I just tried and didnt work. It cant load some classes).

Comment: @EijiAdachi: I was afraid of that, hence [my question initially](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129551/how-do-i-know-if-one-class-is-superclass-of-another-given-that-i-only-have-the/30129629#comment48369208_30129551). Perhaps the [class loader suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129551/how-do-i-know-if-one-class-is-superclass-of-another-given-that-i-only-have-the/30129629#comment48373977_30130539) from Brian?

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder : That worked, but first I had to build a proper URLClassLoader instance. I will post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an `IType` in your question I assume you are using JDT. In this case you can query all supertypes (classes and interfaces) of an `IType` by creating its `ITypeHierarchie`.

The only thing to watch out for is that `java.lang.Object` will not be included in the `ITypeHierarchie` (see [Javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2FITypeHierarchy.html&anchor=getAllSupertypes(org.eclipse.jdt.core.IType)) of `ITypeHierarchy.getAllSupertypes`), so you need to check for that separately.

```
if (class1.equals("java.lang.Object")
    return true;
ITypeHierarchy typeHierarchy = type.newTypeHierarchy(new NullProgressMonitor());
IType[] supertypes = typeHierarchy.getAllSupertypes(type);
boolean isSuperType = Arrays.asList(supertypes).stream().anyMatch(supertype -> {
    return supertype.getFullyQualifiedName().equals(class1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One option you can do is to get the Class objects using `Class.forName()` and then check inheritance using `obj.getSuperClass()` and `obj.getCanonicalName()`.  The following program demonstrates this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class str = Class.forName("java.lang.String");
        Class ex = Class.forName("java.lang.StringBuilder");
        Class superStr = str;
        Class superEx = ex;

        Boolean strIsSuperEx = false;
        Boolean exIsSuperStr = false;
        Boolean bothClassesExist = true;

        while((!strIsSuperEx && !exIsSuperStr) && bothClassesExist) {
            if (superStr != null) {
                superStr = superStr.getSuperclass();
            }
            if (superEx != null) {
                superEx = superEx.getSuperclass();
            }
            bothClassesExist = (superStr != null) && (superEx != null);
            if (superStr != null) {
                String canonicalName = superStr.getCanonicalName();
                String exName = ex.getCanonicalName();
                exIsSuperStr = exName.equals(canonicalName);
            }
            if (superEx != null) {
                String canonicalName = superEx.getCanonicalName();
                String strName = str.getCanonicalName();
                strIsSuperEx = strName.equals(canonicalName);
            }
        }

        if (strIsSuperEx) {
            System.out.println(str.getCanonicalName() + " is a superclass of " + ex.getCanonicalName());
        } else if (exIsSuperStr) {
            System.out.println(ex.getCanonicalName() + " is a superclass of " + str.getCanonicalName());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Neither class is a superclass of the other.");
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work in the context of an eclipse plugin

Comment: You'll need to use `forName(String name, boolean initialize, ClassLoader loader)` instead, passing in the appropriate ClassLoader instance.

Comment: That worked, but first I had to build a proper URLClassLoader. I'll post the answer.